# How to install gtk in python2.7?

Tags: python, gtk

I'm using Debian 6.04 and Python 2.7
I compiled Python 2.7 ,(./configure,make,make install)
in the console:

```
>python2.7  
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 28 2012, 16:54:06) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

How do I install gtk in Python 2.7?

In Python 2.6:

```
tiger@debian:~$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 27 2010, 00:02:40) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gtk
>>> import pygtk
>>> import gobject
```

Comment: Please don't do a `sudo pip install` on your system (as some of the answers recommend). It bypasses the main package management system and this can become a headache when upgrading. Either use a virtualenv or use the version of pygtk available in the standard debian repository and apt-get it. Why are you compiling Python? Is 2.7 not packaged in Debian?

Answer (score 5):

Try installing it using pip/python-pip/easy_install.
On Fedora I installed it like this:

```
sudo pip install PyGTK
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I am getting this error `Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows.`

Comment: You can also go just `pygtk`. It's not case sensitive

Answer (score 3):

I would normaly create a virtualenv based on python 2.7 using

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 .
```

and then install your package inside the virtualenv.

However, `pygtk` is an awkward exception: it can only be install through PyPI on a Windows platform, because some of its dependencies (for the Posix version) are not available of PyPI.

On Debian, install the PyGTK package system-wide with

```
$ sudo pip install PyGTK
```

Comment: ever find out how?

Answer (score 3):

For Windows:

```
pip install PyGTK
```

For MacOS:

```
brew install pygtk
```

- note that this works out of the box with the brew-installed python2 (for me, that's in `/usr/local/Cellar/python\@2/2.7.15/bin/python2.7`). In order to use it with python installed by other means make sure you append PYTHONPATH.

For Ubuntu: (to work with the system-installed python2)

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2-dev
```

Conda:

```
conda install -c ostrokach gtk
```

- if you have python2 running in a conda environment.