# Python Pyhive module cannot import name hive

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, hive, pyhive

I want to connect Python to hive using pyhive. I'm using the below python script to be executed on my local.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from pyhive import hive
from TCLIService.ttypes import TOperationState
def mysql_connect(host, port, username):
 conn = hive.Connection(host=host, port=port, username=username)
 return conn.cursor()

cursor = mysql_connect("localhost", 50070, "hduser")
cursor.execute("show databases")
print_log(cursor)
```

I have pyhive present to the location **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages** but I end up in the following output

```
vaibhav@vaibhav-Lenovo-G570:~/Desktop/Python/Automation$ ./pyhive_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyhive_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    cursor = mysql_connect("localhost", 50070, "hduser")
  File "./pyhive_test.py", line 6, in mysql_connect
    conn = hive.Connection(host=host, port=port, username=username)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 131, in __init__
    self._transport.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 80, in open
    status, payload = self._recv_sasl_message()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 101, in _recv_sasl_message
    payload = read_all_compat(self._trans, length)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thrift_sasl/six.py", line 31, in <lambda>
    read_all_compat = lambda trans, sz: trans.readAll(sz)
  File "/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 60, in readAll
    chunk = self.read(sz - have)
  File "/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 132, in read
    message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes
```

**Edits**
1. Name of the files was changed from Pyhive to pyhive_test

2. pyhive.py was deleted from the directory

**Possible solution tried:**
1.There were installed two versions of python2.7 and python 3.4. I
    uninstalled Python3.4 but still the folder seems to be present in
    /usr/local/lib/. I ran some of the commands below to check where my python is installed and packages available in PYTHONPATH

```
vaibhav@vaibhav-Lenovo-G570:~$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
vaibhav@vaibhav-Lenovo-G570:~$ python -c "import sys, pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)"
['',
 '/home/vaibhav',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/vaibhav/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

2. Got the reference from the link mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963386/python-cant-find-modules-with-pythonpath-set) they mentioned to use it in virtual enviroment  or use clean anaconda. Not used any of them how and don't know how it will affect already existing configuration .

3.I installed Pyhive using sudo, so i changed permission following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/cannot-import-a-python-module-that-is-definitely-installed-mechanize) but still got the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you're starting is named `pyhive.py`.

When you do

```
from pyhive import hive
```

inside your `pyhive.py`, then it will try to import `hive` from **your** module, not from the `pyhive` library.

Please name the file you're starting something else and avoid it to use names of existing modules/libraries.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - the installation-dependent default.

Comment: I changed it to pyhive_test, still getting the same error

Comment: Could you please update your question and add the new error message? Did you make sure there's no longer a file ``pyhive.py`` in the same directory as ``pyhive_test.py``?

Comment: I see you have updated the question, but you clearly still have a file ``pyhive.py`` in the same directory. Please remove it.

Comment: @codaholic Seems your original question "Python Pyhive module cannot import name hive" is now answered, while you now got a different problem with ``hive.Connection``. I suggest you create a new question if you need assistance with the new problem and accept my answer if it was helpful in solving the original problem.

Comment: Accepted. I will post a new question if you know about the new issue please post your answer there as well